# Weird Noise from Front Right Wheel when driving between 90kmph and 105kmph

Tags: noise, dodge

I am driving a 2005 Dodge Grand Caravan. The noise started happening after I had a bump to the curb on a snowy day early this year. The right wheel bumped to the curb during a left turn. The damage made to the wheel bad enough that I had to replace it. Since then, I had the whole 4 tires replaced, did a couple of times tire rotation but the noise never went away. The alignment was done once during the tire replacement but not sure if it was done thoroughly. I asked one car shop to a road test to figure out what was causing it but the mechanic wasn't able to find anything. I was also told that it couldn't be a balance issue since the vehicle would go vibrate if it is.

Any suggestions are appreciated. It's bothering me quite a bit.

Cheers.

Comment: You never mentioned the type of sound you are getting.  We cannot discern if it's a grind with grizzle or a squealing, or a humming, or an interval knocking.  This type of information could possibly help us to give you a more accurate answer.  Please put us at the scene.

Answer (score 2):

Most weird noises from the wheel area turn out to be wheel bearings.

I'd also check to make sure that the disc brake dust shield didn't get bent, as it can make a similar sound when rubbing against the disc.

Answer (score 2):

Try putting the car in neutral when you can hear the noise. If it goes away, it might be the transmission or some part of the drive train.

Push and pull on the top of the front right tire pretty hard and see if you can feel any looseness. If so, it's probably the wheel bearing / hub. But sometimes the wheel bearings go out and still feel tight.

Comment: And some cars, notably VW's, the bearings can feel loose, but be fine...  :-)

Answer (score 2):

The same thing happened to me:  left turn, snow, slip, and hit the curb with the back end of the front tire.  This caused the **Lower Tie Rod** to jump the threaded nuts and threw my alignment off.  I had an alignment done and it was now 95% better.  Bumping a front wheel this way can cause damage to your Inner Tie Rod, Outer Tie rod, Hub Bearing, CV Joint, and CV Boots.